# Saving a webview as html and pdf

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I am creating a browser like application in cocoa. I want to save a web view as an html and PDF file in my hard disk . Please guide me how to proceed. An example will be very helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you want help with?

Comment: I simply want a webview frame loaded with a url to save in a pdf.

i have tried this:</br>

NSData *pdfData = [webView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[webView frame]];
PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:pdfData];

[document writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/tmp/test.pdf"]];

its not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got the answer? If not try this one.

```
    NSData *pdfData = [[[[webview mainFrame] frameView] documentView] dataWithPDFInsideRect:[[[webview mainFrame] frameView] documentView].frame]; 
PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:pdfData];
[document writeToFile:@"/Users/MyName/Desktop/test.pdf"];
```